# #elif defined without parentheses

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, c-preprocessor

Using VS2005 with BLAH_BLAH defined the following preprocessor conditional is false:

```
#elif defined BLAH_BLAH
```

but if I change it to

```
#elif defined(BLAH_BLAH)
```

it is true.

Why do the parentheses make a difference here?

Comment: Parentheses make a different many places in C++. `f(x)` isn't the same as `f x` either. Why would you expect to be able to arbitrarily remove parentheses?

Comment: @jalf: You can use both, see http://www.imb-jena.de/~gmueller/kurse/c_c++/c_defned.html

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd(VS.80).aspx claims that both work.  They both evaluate to true when I try this in GCC.

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference. If there is, it must be a bug in the compiler. A quick experiment with VS2005 does not reproduce your problem. Are you sure that it really happens?

Comment: Post a snippet that actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: @jalf: Because the standard explicitly says you can in this case. The *constant-expression* in a `#if` or `#elif` directory may contain expressions of the form `defined` *`identifier`* or `defined (` *`identifier`* `)`; the two forms are equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header file was created with a linux editor and added to the project with "Add Existing", after creating the file in the VS editor it evaluates to true.  Must be a LF/CR issue?

Comment: I'd be surprised if that were the cause. I don't expect you to be able to resolve this 4 years later, but I wonder whether the file created with the Linux editor might have had some subtle difference from the one created with the VS editor, perhaps a typo in the identifier. Or it might be a bug in VS's handling of `#elif`; see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/29571936/827263

Answer (score 8):

It shouldn't make any difference, unless BLAH_BLAH is defined as something funny.