# Use of #elif in mingw

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mingw

I am currently porting some code from Visual studio to mingw and apparently the following code seems to work in Visual Studio but fails in Mingw

```
#if defined(BATCH_TRIANGLESTRIP)
static const size_t VERT_COUNT = 4;
#elif defined(BATCH_TRIANGLELIST)
static const size_t VERT_COUNT = 6;
#elif //error here on mingw
#error BATCH_TRIANGLESTRIP or BATCH_TRIANGLELIST need to be defined
#endif
```

My question is with the last `#elif` I looked over at the documentation of [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd.aspx) and apparently they dont have  a `#elif` statement without a condition. I wanted to know will the equivalent of above code in mingw be

```
 #if defined(BATCH_TRIANGLESTRIP)
    static const size_t VERT_COUNT = 4; 
    #elif defined(BATCH_TRIANGLELIST)
    static const size_t VERT_COUNT = 6; 
    #else
    #error BATCH_TRIANGLESTRIP or BATCH_TRIANGLELIST need to be defined
    #endif
```

This is the error I get with the original code

```
error: #elif with no expression
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#elif` requires a constant expression according to the C++ standard (and the C standard as well). The failure to diagnose a bare `#elif` is a bug in Visual Studio.

The equivalent in standard C++ would use `#else` rather than `#elif`. Both Visual Studio and MinGW should handle that correctly -- as should any conforming compiler.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5223789/827263) *might* point to another bug in VS's handling of `#elif`.